# Different Color text with DrawText() In Python

Tags: python, user-interface, winapi, text, gdi

## Hey!

So I am having some fun with GDI effects and I have some text, and I have filled out all of the arguments, and there is no, color option. So I am confused on how to change the color from something like the plain white background, to a red background. I have tried a multitude of options and I couldn't figure it out. Any Help?

Here is the code to place text:

(If you can't get it to run go to `cmd` and type in `pip install pywin32`)

```py
from win32gui import *
from win32api import *
from win32ui import *
from win32con import *
from random import *
from time import *

desk = GetDC(0)

x = GetSystemMetrics(0)
y = GetSystemMetrics(1)

text = "Hello World"

for i in range(1500):
    DrawText(desk, text, len(text), (randrange(x), randrange(y), randrange(x), randrange(y)), DT_LEFT)
```

Comment: See [device contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts).

Comment: I suggest you could try to use [SetTextColor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-settextcolor?redirectedfrom=MSDN) sets the text color for the specified device context to the specified color.

Answer (score 1):

This will print red text on a black background.

```
from win32gui import *
from win32api import *
from win32ui import *
from win32con import *
from random import *
from time import *

desk = GetDC(0)

x = GetSystemMetrics(0)
y = GetSystemMetrics(1)

text = "Hello World"

SetTextColor(desk, 255)
SetBkColor(desk, 0)
for i in range(1500):
    DrawText(desk, text, len(text), (randrange(x), randrange(y), randrange(x), randrange(y)), DT_LEFT)
```

Try using **SetTextColor()** and **SetBkColor()**.
Sorry for the translator.